# Android: Widget+Service no empty constructor

Tags: android, android-widget

I created a news widget. It gets JSON from server then parses it and shows it to the user. But at the beginning I get an error, see below. I also tried without service, only `AsyncTask`, and I still had the error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

What should I do?

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private RemoteViews update;
    private ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> timestamp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, GetNews.class);
    int[] appWidgetId = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), GetNews.class);
    intent.putExtra("appWidgetIds", appWidgetIds);

        context.startService(intent);
    }

        public String getTime(String time, Context context){
            long jsonTimestamp = Long.parseLong(time);
            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
            Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone, locale);
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(jsonTimestamp * 1000);
            CharSequence date = DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(context, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE,0);

            final long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 1000*60;
            final int HOUR_MILLIS = 1000*60*60;
            final int DAY_MILLIS = 1000*60*60*24;

            if(diff < 24*HOUR_MILLIS){
                SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                String format = s.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                return format+"";
            }
            else {
                return  date+"";
            }

        }

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
         public void WidgetUpdate(Context context){

    }
        class  LoadBitmap extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{

            String Url = "http://www.gazeta.uz/i/gazetauz-logo-120.gif";
            public void loadImage(String url){
                if(url != null){
                this.Url = url;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                InputStream ips = null;
                try {
                    ips = new URL(Url).openConnection().getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ips);
                return bitmap;
            }
        }

    class LoadNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
            InputStream ips = null;
            String jstring = null;
            JSONObject json = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet("mysite");
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
                ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){
                   str.append(line);
                }
                ips.close();
                jstring = str.toString();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jstring);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
        }

        public class GetNews extends Service {
            @Override
            public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
               AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
               RemoteViews update = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main);
               Context context = getBaseContext();
               int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra("appWidgetIds");
                ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getBaseContext(), Widget.class);
                int[] appWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

               for(int appWidgets : appWidgetIds){
               LoadNews news = new LoadNews();
               news.execute();

                    try {
                        JSONObject result = news.get();
                        if(result != null){
                            JSONArray jarray = result.optJSONArray("data");
                            title.clear();
                            images.clear();
                            url.clear();
                            for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject jrss = jarray.optJSONObject(i);
                                title.add(jrss.optString("title"));
                                images.add(jrss.optString("img"));
                                url.add(jrss.optString("url"));
                                timestamp.add(jrss.optInt("publish_timestamp"));
                            }
                            update.setTextViewText(R.id.text, title.get(0).substring(0, 65)+"...");
                            update.setTextViewText(R.id.text2,title.get(1).substring(0, 65)+"...");
                            update.setTextViewText(R.id.text3, title.get(2).substring(0, 65)+"...");
                            update.setTextViewText(R.id.text4, title.get(3).substring(0, 65)+"...");

                            update.setTextViewText(R.id.text_1, getTime(timestamp.get(0) + "", context));
                            update.setTextViewText(R.id.text_2,  getTime(timestamp.get(1) + "", context));
                            update.setTextViewText(R.id.text_3,  getTime(timestamp.get(2) + "", context));
                            update.setTextViewText(R.id.text_4,  getTime(timestamp.get(3)+"",context));


                            update.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.get(0))), 0));
                            update.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text2, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.get(1))), 0));

                            LoadBitmap bitmap = new LoadBitmap();
                            bitmap.loadImage(images.get(0));
                            bitmap.execute();
                            update.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmap.get());

                            LoadBitmap bitmap2 = new LoadBitmap();
                            bitmap2.loadImage(images.get(1));
                            bitmap2.execute();
                            update.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView2, bitmap2.get());

                            LoadBitmap bitmap3 = new LoadBitmap();
                            bitmap3.loadImage(images.get(2));
                            bitmap3.execute();
                            update.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView3, bitmap3.get());

                            LoadBitmap bitmap4 = new LoadBitmap();
                            bitmap4.loadImage(images.get(3));
                            bitmap4.execute();
                            update.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView4, bitmap4.get());
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(startId, update);
               }
                stopSelf();
               super.onStart(intent, startId);
            }

            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**LogCat**

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.afishamedia.widget.Widget$GetNews: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.afishamedia.widget.Widget$GetNews; no empty constructor
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2637)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.afishamedia.widget.Widget$GetNews; no empty constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2634)
    ... 10 more
```